# What double nested brackets means in python numpy array when it is printed?

Tags: python, numpy

I have screenshot of python code:

[image]

Is X row vector or one dimensional vector or just numpy array with no dimension?

Is X2 column vector or 2 dimensional matrix? Does the the two nested brackets in X2 output means it is 2 dimensional matrix and if so how do I change it to column vector with single bracket when it is printed like the output of X?

Comment: `print(X2[0])` - can you interpret what you see?

Comment: `X` is 1d with shape (10,) (that's a 1 element tuple). `X2` is 2d, (10,1). One layer of [] per dimension.

Comment: row vector, column vector, matrix are not documented numpy terms.

Answer (score -1):

The double square bracket denotes that it is a 2-dimensional array.